# ui-state-highlight not set after rebuilding p:tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I use a p:tree to display my datastructure. If I select a TreeNode I can edit it's properties and save it or delete the Node. After deleting od saving a Node i rebuild the whole tree. After the rebuild I search for the Node I edited to put it back in my "selection" variable. Everithing works fine except for highlighting the selected Node. The HTML-Element just does't get the styleclass "ui-state-highlight".

How can I forece the "reselection" in browser?

I use:
 - PrimeFaces 6.2
 - Java 8 Update 161
 - WildFly 8.2.1.Final

Example of my p:tree:

```
<p:tree id="project-tree" dynamic="true" value="# projectTree.projectTreeRootNode}" var="node" styleClass="pro-tree" selectionMode="single" selection="#{projectTree.selectedNode}">

    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{projectTree.onNodeExpand}" process="@this" update=":project-forms" />
    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{projectTree.onNodeCollapse}" process="@this" update=":project-forms" />
    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{projectTree.onNodeSelect}" process="@this" update=":project-forms" />

    <p:treeNode styleClass="pro-treenode #{node.styleClass}">
        <i class="#{node.icon}" aria-hidden="true"></i> #{node.label}
    </p:treeNode>

</p:tree>
```

Quick and dirty solution to cyle through my nodes:

```
if (null != selectedNode)
{
  Boolean found = false;
  for (TreeNode childNode : projectTreeRootNode.getChildren())
  {
    found = findSelectedNode(childNode, childNode.getParent());
    if (found == true)
    {
      break;
    }
    for (TreeNode childChildNode : childNode.getChildren())
    {
      found = findSelectedNode(childChildNode, childChildNode.getParent());
      if (found == true)
      {
        break;
      }
      for (TreeNode childChildChildNode : childChildNode.getChildren())
      {
        found = findSelectedNode(childChildChildNode, childChildChildNode.getParent());
        if (found == true)
        {
          break;
        }
        for (TreeNode childChildChildChildNode : childChildChildNode.getChildren())
        {
          found = findSelectedNode(childChildChildChildNode, childChildChildChildNode.getParent());
          if (found == true)
          {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  onNodeSelect();
}
```

Code to find my previous selected Node:

```
private Boolean findSelectedNode(TreeNode tn, TreeNode tnParent)
{
    PROTreeNodeData dataSelected = (PROTreeNodeData) selectedNode.getData();
    PROTreeNodeData dataTn = (PROTreeNodeData) tn.getData();

    if (tnParent.getData().toString().contains("Root"))
    {
      if (dataSelected.getLabel().equals(dataTn.getLabel()) && dataSelected.getType().equals(dataTn.getType()))
      {
        selectedNode = tn;
        return true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      TreeNode tnSelectedParent = selectedNode.getParent();

      PROTreeNodeData selectedParentData = (PROTreeNodeData) tnSelectedParent.getData();
      PROTreeNodeData tnParentData = (PROTreeNodeData) tnParent.getData();

      if (dataSelected.getLabel().equals(dataTn.getLabel()) && dataSelected.getType().equals(dataTn.getType()) && selectedParentData.getLabel().equals(tnParentData.getLabel()) && selectedParentData.getType().equals(tnParentData.getType()))
      {
        selectedNode = tn;
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: _"Quick and dirty solution to cyle through my nodes:"_ It's not quick (in development). Doing it in a recursive method is quicker (and less code) ;-) And please, for code not working, always provide a [mcve]...

Comment: adding `selectedNode.setSelected(true);` after finding the Node does the job.